# Laravel + CKEditor + Laravel File Manager – do not display images

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor4.x

my form:

```
<form>
    <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
    </textarea>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token={{csrf_token()}}'
    };

    setTimeout(function(){
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', options );
    },100);
</script>
```

my route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/laravel-filemanager', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\LfmController@show');
    Route::post('/laravel-filemanager/upload', '\UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Controllers\UploadController@upload');
});
```

[image]

Ckeditor is displayed. When I click on the img icon a window will open. But no files will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Make sure you publish the vendor files

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public
```

and clear the cache

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```

It is also essential that the .env has the correct domain address.

Finally replace your routes with

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
 \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
```

});